# After switching to Devuan, how do I remove systemd?

Tags: debian, systemd, sysvinit, devuan

So, I've also switched from Debian to the Devuan pseudo-fork. But - this doesn't get rid of systemd... I've followed the instructions [here](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_a_Debian_jessie/sid_installation), and did:

```
# apt-get install sysvinit-core sysvinit-utils
```

but when I then tried:

```
# apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove systemd
```

I got basically the following error message:

```
systemd is the active init system, please switch to another before removing systemd.
```

Yeah great, just what I thought I was trying to do..

Comment: Do it from a chroot...

Comment: @jasonwryan: Can you be more specific? chroot to where? And why would this help? And are you sure it won't render the system unbootable?

Comment: You have two choices. Boot from a live medium, chroot in and change it, or boot from Devuan and then remove systemd. No, I am not sure it won't render the system unbootable because I know nothing about Devuan...

Answer (score 5):

You have to reboot your machine after executing first command.

Please take a look at [How to remove systemd from a Debian jessie/sid installation](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_a_Debian_jessie/sid_installation).

Comment: No, that doesn't help at all, systemd runs after the reboot as well.

Comment: @einpoklum well there's ALT Linux out there just in case, we ship both systemd and sysvinit (but most of the docs and discussions are in Russian).  Maybe my en.altlinux.org/rescue would be helpful back then either -- boot, mount, chroot, replace init, reboot.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. error reason

this error came from here:

/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.prerm

```
# Prevent systemd from being removed if it's the active init.  That
# will not work.
#

if [ "$1" = "remove" ] && [ -e /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd ]; then
    echo "systemd is the active init system, please switch to another before removing systemd."
    exit 1
fi
```

### 2. resolve & remove

see systemd cgroup mounts (mounted by `/lib/systemd/systemd`)

```
mount
...
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/debug type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,debug)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
```

umount them, and try to remove again:

```
apt-get remove systemd
```

OR

```
apt-get purge systemd
```

that's worked for me.

### 3. after remove

then other service manager maybe needed,
`sysvinit` or `upstart` or something else.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't test this right now since I don't have Devuan installed at the moment...