# Netstat display wrong process associated to listening port

Tags: debian, netstat

When I do `netstat -tanup` as root on my Debian host, process `1/init` is displayed for port 993. How is this possible ? I never saw such behavior.

The command `systemctl list-sockets` shows the correct service `dovecot` associated to port 993.

**EDIT**: I noticed another strange thing: Sytemd reports that davecot is listening on port 143 (imap) and dovecot is configured to not listen on port 143. I get a warning in the logs about that: `dovecot: master: Error: systemd listens on port 143, but it's not configured in Dovecot. Closing.: 2 Time(s)`

Comment: It seems to be a feature of the way that systemd works - see for example [init(pid=1) listen on port 9418(git)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188038) - would love to hear a real answer though

Comment: I noticed this on my machine too. How is this a feature? - just seems like a vector of attack to me, and I have these installed and it stills show `1/init`, time for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218933/after-switching-to-devuan-how-do-i-remove-systemd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default dovecot run `pop` , `imap` , `pop3` and `imaps` on the [following ports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot):

```
110: pop
143: imap
995: pop3s
993: imaps
```

install `dovecot-pop3d` then copy `dovecot.socket` to `/etc/systemd`

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/dovecot.socket /etc/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl reenable dovecot.socket
```

Modify `dovecot.socket`:

```
sudo sed -i '/:143$/s/^/#/' /etc/systemd/system/dovecot.socket
```

Restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl stop dovecot.service
sudo systemctl start dovecot.socket
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Check the status:

```
sudo systemctl status dovecot.socket
```

Comment: Why do you tell me to install `dovecot-pop3d` if I only need and use imaps ? Does the sed line simply comment out lines with port 143 ?

Comment: Yes it will comment out lines with port 143

Comment: I have test it on my debian jessie . Can you try it ?

Comment: I'll try it. It seam more appropriate to create a symbolic link `ln -s /lib/systemd/system/dovecot.socket /etc/systemd/system` as this is what has been done for ssh I see.

Comment: it will e created after runing : `systemctl reenable dovecot.socket`

Comment: What should be the permissions of the `/etc/systemd/system/dovecot.socket` ? Is it ok to be root:root 0644 or should it be 0666 ? I'm  slow because I use ansible and edit the script. I also double check everything ;)

Comment: Is it equivalent to copy a file with lines :143 commented out into /ect/systemd/system, then reeanable, then stop, start, daemon-reload ?

Comment: Copy then symlink  , stop and start service

Comment: The copy is not needed. I should apparently directly modify/replace /lib/systemd/system/dovecot.socket. Then we don't need the reenable because there is already a link in /etc/systemd/system/socket.target.wants to this dovecot.socket file.

Comment: Ok. It works. I overwrote the  /lib/systemd/system/dovecot.socket file with the commented out lines with 143 ports. Then the reeanable was required because it doesn't simply create a link. Apparently systemd updates its state. After that netstat showed dovecot instead of init. Don't know if the systemctl daemon-reload is required.

Comment: If you don't get an error like `Warning: Unit file changed on disk, 'systemctl daemon-reload' recommended.` it is not required

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying files:

```
sudo systemctl stop dovecot.service
sudo systemctl stop dovecot.socket
sudo systemctl mask dovecot.socket
sudo systemctl start dovecot.service
```

and enjoy `netstat -tanup` ouput...

Comment: Do you mind explaining this magic. What does `mask dovecot.socket` do ? Why stopping socket and not start socket ?