# How do I install newer or older versions of GCC on Devuan/Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, gcc, compiler

Some distributions come with package sets for different versions of GCC, which you can easily install in parallel; others do not. Specifically, in Devuan ASCII / Debian Stretch, there only seem to be GCC 6 packages.

What's the right way to install additional versions of GCC in parallel to v6? Is there a special repository like the Ubuntu-targeted PPAs (e.g. `ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1`)? I'd rather avoid adding apt sources which need updating for newer versions of Debian (e.g. sid).

Comment: Having used Debian and switched to Devuan, I still have several versions of gcc installed in parallel (and regularly have to delete older ones). So my guess would be "add apt sources, pin apt to ASCII (google "apt-pinning") to avoid updating, install other gcc versions as required".

Comment: I am in Debian 9 without systemd...is the switch problematic? Never tried it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: No, I don't think you are. IIANM, Debian 9 cannot run without `systemd`. The switch is very easy if you come from Debian, except that you (probably) won't be using the Gnome desktop environment. If you're used to XFCE, LXQt, Cinnamon or Mate then you're good, and probably KDE also. Almost all packages in Devuan are simply the Debian packages of the corresponding release,

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Having said that - switching without reinstalling your distribution may not be simple/possible, See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218933/34868) about my problems doing that.

Comment: using Debian 9 with Sys V in server vms...the only thing I cannot get rid of is systemd-udev, and I have not yet invested time on it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I would actually guess you have SysV on top of systemd. If what you described was possible, Devuan would not have been necessary.

Comment: Devuan is to get ridding of all dependencies and fluffs. I actually getting away because I do not run X.org or gnome. I still have some unwanted dependencies on binaries, but I am not running systemd besides the ill fated udev in a couple hundred Debian VMs since Debian 7?. I have actually several systemd related packages pinned to -1.

Comment: #dpkg -S /sbin/init    answer: sysvinit-core

Comment: @einpoklum Rui is right, it *is* possible to run Debian 9 without systemd, unless you use GNOME. So on a server it’s entirely doable. If you have `sysvinit-core` installed, it’s not `sysvinit` on top of systemd, it’s instead of systemd. Switching from one to the other doesn’t involve reinstalling either (but it does involve rebooting).